# Is it possible to Insert data in one table and select data from another in same query in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables say: `table1` and `table2`. The primary key(id) of the table1 is a foreign key in table2. I want to insert data in table2. Say, name, id, contact. I also want a column from the table1 where the id matches. I can do them in separate queries.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(NAME,ID,CONTACT) VALUES('ABC', 'QWERTY', 1234);

SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID='QWERTY';
```

But is it possible in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done using [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_row as (
  INSERT INTO TABLE1(NAME,ID,CONTACT) 
  VALUES('ABC', 'QWERTY', 1234)
  returning id
)
select *
from table2
where id in (select id from new_row);
```